# Is there a workaround for LEGO Harry Potter Years 5-7 freezing during year 6 on the Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

During the year 6 mission "A Not So Merry Christmas" the game freezes when I start putting out the fires.

From what I can tell, it's a problem specific to the Wii version of the game, has anyone experienced this, and if so have you figured out a work around?

Comment: Are you playing in co-op? I had a similar problem with LEGO Batman on Wii, it would crash at the same time in co-op. Playing solo got us past the problematic point.

Comment: @Adeese The crashes are happening in solo.

Comment: From an edit to the question: "I have found that you can get further if you only have one player, but it looks like it pushes the Wii too far and it crashes."  ... I think it should be obvious that 1 player will have less processing but in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure how reliable is [this source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0051TL964), but here it is:

> My son was really excited to get this game last Friday. Unfortunately,
>   his enjoyment has been tempered by the extreme bugginess of the
>   release. **Since he made it to the 6th year, the game has crashed
>   constantly. We finally called customer service this morning and were
>   informed that it has been recalled. We will be sent a new disk in the
>   mail.**

There are other sites that talk about LEGO Harry Potter 5-7 recall, so probably it is better that you contact the customer service too, or your game reseller.

A possible fix it suggested [here](http://www.guide4games.com/index.php/fixes/876-lego-harry-potter-years-5-7-pc-crashes-blackscreen-freezes-crash-to-desktop-ctd-no-sound-errors-and-fixes) at Guide4Games.

> Adjust sound settings to "Stereo" or "Mono" from "Surround":
>
> 1. In Wii Channel menu -> Select Wii Options -> Press A Button
> 2. Go to Wii Settings -> Press A Button
> 3. In Wii Settings menu -> Go to Sound -> Press A Buttton
> 4. Select "Stereo" or "Mono" -> Press A Button to confirm
> 5. Re-start LEGO Harry Potter Years 5-7

Comment: I phoned WB tech support Jan 16, 2012 and was informed that replacement discs are not being provided (except for a few very early editions that were released accidentally).  They are only suggesting work arounds, all of which are listed here.

Answer (score 7):

I know others have already posted something very similar to this, but just in case they weren't 'clear' enough for someone.

For anybody trying to get past the crash point in Book 6 while trying to extinguish the fires;

1. Turn your Wii audio settings to Mono.
2. Turn the screen resolution to 480i.
3. Turn the aspect ratio to 4:3.
4. Play through the level with ONLY Remus, and play through it slowly.

This WILL work. I JUST completed it successfully following these steps.

You'll have to use Arthur Weasley to build the wagon.

Answer (score 5):

There is a work around for this issue, which I have been able to perform ... it's not as good as a fix but it'll do for now.

The bug seems to be too much video processing for the poor Wii.  So to mitigate the amount of video elements work the top left first.  Dig up any spots that need it to get rid of the paw print animations.  Put together the fire extinguisher and use it to put out the fires.

Most of all, just SLOW DOWN ... if you exercise some patience in this area you can clear it out and proceed with the rest of the game.

Answer (score 0):

According to WB Tech support (Jan 16, 2012) the main problem setting seems to be with the Wii audio set to "Surround", a default on many systems.  Downgrading this setting to stereo or mono will help remedy the problem.

Additionally they suggest the "SLOW DOWN" work around.  They say that the game is an exact port between consoles (Wii/XBox360/PS3) and that the lower processing power of the Wii is what is causing the freeze up.